# Evaluate the following trigonometric limit:

Tags: calculus, limits

> Question: Evaluate the following limit $$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{\sin \left\{\frac{2}{n}\right\}}{\left[2 n \tan \frac{1}{n}\right]\left(\tan \frac{1}{n}\right)}+\frac{1}{n^{2}+\cos n}\right)^{n^{2}}$$ here {} and [] denote the fractional part function and the greatest integer function respectively.

> Answer: The answer of this question is given as $1$, the problem is from an JEE Advanced practice problems set.

> My approach: I figured out that this is the $1^{\infty}$ form, so I tried to convert it in the form $$e^{\lim_{{n}\rightarrow{\infty}}n^{2}.G(n)}$$ here $G(n)$ is the function within the brackets, after this step I am not able to proceed as the limit in the power of $e$ is very messy and not convertible into some standard form, please help.

Comment: You could perhaps use $\sin(2x) = \frac{2\tan(x)}{1 + \tan^2(x)}$

Comment: How do I deal with the fractional part function then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$, we have for $n>2$

$$\begin{align}
\sin(\{2/n\})&=\sin\left(2/n-\lfloor2/n\rfloor\right)\\\\
&=\sin(2/n)\cos(\lfloor2/n\rfloor)-\cos(2/n)\sin(\lfloor2/n\rfloor)\\\\
&=\sin(2/n)\\\\
&=2\sin(1/n)\cos(1/n)
\end{align}$$

In addition, for $n>2$, $\lfloor2n \tan(\frac1n)\rfloor=2$.

Hence, we can write for $n>2$

$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\sin(\{2/n\})}{\lfloor2n \tan(\frac1n)\rfloor \tan(1/n)}+\frac1{n^2+\cos(n)}\right)^{n^2}&=\left(\cos^2(1/n)+\frac1{n^2+\cos(n)}\right)^{n^2}\\\\
&=\left(1+O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)\right)^{n^2}
\end{align}$$

whereupon letting $n\to \infty$ yields the coveted limit

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sin(\{2/n\})}{\lfloor2n \tan(\frac1n)\rfloor \tan(1/n)}+\frac1{n^2+\cos(n)}\right)^{n^2}=1$$

Comment: a very elegant solution, thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: how did you obtain the $n^{4}$ term in the third step of your solution?

Comment: Note that $$\cos^2(1/n)=\left(1-\frac1{n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)\right)$$and$$ \frac1{n^2+\cos(n)}=\frac{1}{n^2}\left(1-\frac{\cos(n)}{n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)\right)=\frac1{n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^4}\right)$$